# Selenium continues after one test

Tags: firefox, selenium, testing, automated-tests, web-testing

I am doing a test case in selenium webdriver and i am fairly new to testing. I am just asking if I am able to continue with a test to test other functionality after an assert has already taken place. Like the example below, Thank you in advance
Ex.

```
search.sendKeys("hello");
search.submit();
assertTrue(....);

search.sendKeys("thank you);
search.submit();
assertTrue(....);
```

Comment: Worth reading: https://www.facebook.com/notes/kent-beck/decompose-run-on-tests/555371804495688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `assert` statement won't fail the test will continue.
If you want to test the second functionality even if the `assert` does fail you should split the test to two different tests.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and time I split the tests into 2 to be more structured and to know if even one test fails and the other succeeds

Answer (score 0):

An Assert is a method that you use to simply check if something is true or not. If it is true it'll pass and continue the execution, if it is not - it will terminate the execution. [Here's more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and time I split the tests into 2 to be more structured and to know if even one test fails and the other succeeds